# How can I make only one table of current table?

Tags: html, html-table

There where a `TEST` I have other table, but wouldn't it be better if it's will only a one table?

```
<Table border="1">
    <Tr>
       <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th colspan="3">
           <table>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid">TEST</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td style="border-right: 1px solid">1</td><td>2</td><td style="border-left: 1px solid">3</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this html I have two tables as you can see, how can I make only one of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without nesting:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
        <td colspan="3">TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gbrqB/)** (your code on top)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. One way would be to make use of the `rowspan` attribute and have 2 header rows. Like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">1</th>
        <th rowspan="2">2</th>
        <th rowspan="2">4</th>
        <th colspan="3">TEST</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/KCnzX/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like below, it will help you..

**HTML :**

```
<table border="1">

<tr>
<td rowspan="2">1</td>
<td  rowspan="2">2</td>
<td  rowspan="2">4</td>
<td colspan="3">Test</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**Output :**

[image]